# objective C and python - pyobjc

Tags: python, objective-c, pyobjc

Is it possible for an objective c application to run python files and read their data, etc?

If so, can someone post code? or lead me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Elijah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, see [the tutorial](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/documentation/pyobjc-core/tutorial_embed/index.html) -- it's very dated but should still apply today.  ([Apple's tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/pyobjc.html) is good, but it only shows how to call ObjC from Python, while pyobjc's own tutorial, while extremely short, focuses on the opposite direction -- calling Python from ObjC -- which appears to be what you want).

Comment: Now, if I wanted to control HOWIE (pyaiml chat bot http://howie.sourceforge.net/) with objective c, how would I do that? I want to make a GUI for HOWIE. BUT, I don't want to use terminal as an interface, I want the GUI to be the interface to get HOWIE's responses and send input.

Comment: I don't know howie (nor does it interest me enough to study it;-) but at worst you can control it with `pyexpect` and write the whole Mac GUI with Xcode, Cocoa, and Python (with PyObjC -- see Apple's tutorial I already pointed to) -- absolutely no need to "run Python code" from "an objective C application";-).  Or, instead of pyexpect, you can look inside howie and use or make a decent Python API for it -- but, again, what does that have to do with objective-c?!

Comment: @Elijah, yep, I'm pretty experienced in Python, but what little free time I have I spend responding on Stack Overflow (where my answers can hopefully be read and used by many people), not on 1-on-1 help which just doesn't scale -- sorry.  If you don't know either Python or Tcl, I don't know how to "drive" a text-mode app you can't change (because you don't know its language, whatever it may be) from a GUI front-end -- `expect` is Tcl, `pyexpect` is Python (I don't know of any equivalent for ObjC).  However, Python is *easy* to learn!-)